# Codeigniter model structure for multiple database system

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, model

I'm looking to implement a multiple database web system. I've been trying to figure out the best way to structure models that extend a base model with acts as the database connection.

Lets say for this discussion I would want to retrieve all records within a table called "users", and I have a database identifier in the session data.

I thought of having some sort of structure to my models like;

```
/Table
  /Account
      /User.php
      /Base.php
  /Base.php
```

My base.php inside the Table folder would have my standard CRUD functionality, I'm thinking performing actions based on the model name?

My Table/Account/Users.php model would extend the Table/Account/Base.php model which peforms the database connection.

What I would like to be able to do is something like;

```
$users = $this->load->model('/Table/Account/User');
$users->get(...);
```

But I think I would need to pass through the database identifier for the Account/Base.php to know which database to connect to?

I might be going completely the wrong direction with this so I would to hear opinions on how I could perform this :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to complicate your whole model logic like that just to use two different database connections. Codeigniter [documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html) has a pretty straight forward example.

In case you are using version 2 of CI, you can use multiple database connections by following these simple rules:

```
$DB1 = $this->load->database('group_one', TRUE);
$DB2 = $this->load->database('group_two', TRUE);
```

> Note: Change the words "group_one" and "group_two" to the specific
>   group names you are connecting to (or you can pass the connection
>   values as indicated above). See more at the [official documentation of
>   the database configuration](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/configuration.html) of codeigniter.

By setting the second parameter to TRUE (boolean) the function will return the database object.

When you connect this way, you will use your object name to issue commands rather than the syntax used throughout this guide. In other words, rather than issuing commands with:

```
$this->db->query();
$this->db->result();
etc...
```

You will instead use:

```
$DB1->query();
$DB1->result();
etc...
```

You can load the database connection object you want in your model constructor, so you can choose what you need there.